# How Many Prime Number exist?

Tags: java, primes

Something is wrong with my code that i can't figure it out, will you help me to find my mistake? Thank you!

```
/// Calculate Prime
private static int countPrimes(int number){
    int count =0;
    for(int i=1; i<=MAX_PRIME; i++) {
        if(isPrime(i)){
        count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Exactly "+  count + " prime numbers exist between "+number + " and 1000."); 
return number;
}
```

here is my result:
Exactly 180 prime numbers exist between 1 and 1000. Which is wrong and has to be 168!!!

Comment: I've reformatted your code. Proper indentation is really helpful.

Comment: what the purpose of this function? the input parameter number seems only to be used in print?

Comment: isPrime is not defined, how are you doing that? also start j at 2 and break if not i%j, there is no reason to run through all i. also you need to zero count every time through. ~Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the function isPrice()? is it a function to check that a integer number is prime number or not? I think that if you have it, you just need to do like this:

```
 for(int i=1; i<=MAX_PRIME; i++) {
     if(isPrime(i)){
        count++
     }
 }
 return count;
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that your implicit parameter, int number, is never used in your program.
Try this code:

```
private static int countPrimes(int number){
    int count =0;
    int countPrimes=0;
    if(number<2)
       return 0;
    for(int i=2; i<=number; i++) { //start i=2, because you know that 1 is not a prime number.
       for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
            if(i%j==0)
                count++;                
        }
        if(count ==2)
            countPrimes++;            
        count=0;
    }
    return number;
}
```

Then, in your runner method, call:

```
int numOfPrimes = countPrimes(10000);
```

In this, you can vary what number you want to count up to. In this example it counts the primes up to 10000.

```
int numOfPrimes = countPrimes(100);
```

This will count primes up to 100. If you want to keep track of the primes, in your program you could add:

```
ArrayList<Integer> listOfPrimes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private static int countPrimes(int number){
    int count =0;
    int countPrimes=0;
    if(number<2)
       return 0;
    for(int i=2; i<=number; i++) { //start i=2, because you know that 1 is not a prime number.
       for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
            if(i%j==0)
                count++;                
        }
        if(count ==2){
            countPrimes++;
            listOfPrimes.add(i);
        }           
        count=0;
    }
    return number;
}
```

In order to retrieve your numbers you could do something like this:

```
System.out.println("Exactly "+  countPrimes(number) + " prime numbers exist between "+ "1" + " and " + number + ".");
System.out.println("These numbers are: ");
for(int i =0; i<listOfPrimes.size();i++){
    System.out.println(listOfPrimes.get(i));
}
```

Comment: why would you return `number`?

Comment: it is enough to only check numbers up to sqrt(i)

Comment: You would need to return number since the method has a return type of int.

Answer (score 1):

The prime count can be found using "Sieve of Eratosthenes".
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Following program will count the no. of primes given the limit.

I am taking the limit = 1000.

```
public class CountPrime {

public static void main(String[] args) {

boolean[] isPrime     = null;
int       Tprimes     = 0;
final int UPPER_BOUND = Integer.parseInt("1000");

/*------------------------------------------------------+
| Assuming all to prime                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------*/
isPrime = new boolean[UPPER_BOUND + 1];
for (int Tindex = 2; Tindex <= UPPER_BOUND; Tindex++) {
  isPrime[Tindex] = true;
} /*end for*/

/*------------------------------------------------------+
| Mark Non-Primes given the Upper Bound                 |
+------------------------------------------------------*/
for (int Tindex = 2; Tindex*Tindex <= UPPER_BOUND; Tindex++) {
  /*------------------------------------------------------+
  | For any prime all the multiples are non-prime         |
  +------------------------------------------------------*/
  if (isPrime[Tindex]) {
    for (int Tver = Tindex; Tindex*Tver <= UPPER_BOUND; Tver++) {
      isPrime[Tindex*Tver] = false;
    } /*end for*/
  } /*end if*/
} /*end for*/

/*------------------------------------------------------+
| Now, as we are done count the total primes            |
+------------------------------------------------------*/
for (int Tindex = 2; Tindex <= UPPER_BOUND; Tindex++) {
  if (isPrime[Tindex]) {
    Tprimes++;
  } /*end if*/
} /*end for*/
System.out.println("Total No. of Primes[" + Tprimes +
                   "], given the limit[" + UPPER_BOUND + "]");
} /*END OF main*/

} /*END OF CountPrime*/
```

Output:
Total No. of Primes[168], given the limit[1000]

Answer (score 0):

I think you return a wrong variable instead of `count`, and if `countPrimes` means to calc the  count of primes between `nunber` and `MaxPrime`, then you should count from `number`, like this:

```
for (int i = number; i<=MAX_PRIME;i++)
```